# antlr displayRecognitionError

Tags: antlr, antlr3

Using antlr 3 with java

I'm having trouble printing the text from the token here:

```
@lexer::members {

    public void displayRecognitionError(String[] tokenNames, RecognitionException e) {
        System.err.println("Encountered an illegal char " + getText() + " on line "+getLine()+":"+getCharPositionInLine ());
    }

}
```

I'm making a more detailed error report for the lexer grammar.

The thing is that when the error occurs (the user enters a token like `:` which isn't defined) it only shows `"Encountered an illegal char on line x:y"`, instead it should show the invalid character `:` between char and on line x:y.

What can I do to show the invalid character, line and column?

Comment: I managed to resolve it.. there was no token since : wasn't defined so I always got nullpointer.. I used e.c instead thanks.